# How to get data from github for an user (person) using restapi in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api, rest

I want to get all data from GitHub for a specific person. When entered the user name to get all the data from Github. I do not get anything except [] on the browser and in console I get Failed to load resource: the server responded with 404(). Below is the method that I created for that. Can someone help me, please. Thank you

```
private void GetGithubData()
    {
        string username = "testUser";
        var url = "https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/repos?page=1";

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "TestApp";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? you should mention what problem you have...

Comment: I do not get anything except [] on the browser and in the console I get Failed to load resource: the server responded with 404()

Comment: in this piece of code, you make a request, and you read it without storing it anywhere. and your problem is you get `[]` and `404` ? please use `print` to log what it reads: `Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());`

Comment: can it be your firewall/proxy? I just tried with my own user and it worked (on the browser) .

Comment: @yaya I tried it and did not work using print to log it

Comment: @TiGreX How can I go around the firewall/proxy?? I start thinking you might be just right

Comment: @CrislyDomingos if you're in a company probably ask for access to https://api.github.com/.

Comment: @TiGreX The IT just replied saying that they cannot grant that to me. Is there a way around it at all??

Comment: @CrislyDomingos can't you use a vpn like hotspotshield ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I have found the mistake. Basically, I have to return the data back. So I have posted the solution below

```
private **string** GetGithubData()
{
    string username = "testUser";
    var url = "https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/repos?page=1";

    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.UserAgent = "TestApp";

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        **return** reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```